# How to fetch an item from chrome's local storage using a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have constructed a front end using Angular and set up authentication using AWS Cogntio, the frontend currently stores an access token to local storage.

I would like to fetch that token and evaluates its validity to unlock a chrome extension but struggling to find the correct syntax to do this.

Angular:

```
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: (session) => {
        localStorage.setItem(
          'AccessToken',
          session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken(),
        );
      },
      onFailure: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    });
```

Extension:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Add a click event listener to the "Fetch Data" button
    document.getElementById('fetchDataButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Fetch data from Chrome storage
        chrome.storage.sync.get("AccessToken", function (obj) {
            console.log("Passed successfully: Access Token " + obj.Accesstoken)
        });
    });
});
```

Unfortunately console.log is printing undefined, printing just the obj gives you [object Object].

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: localStorage is a different storage unrelated to chrome.storage.local or sync.

Comment: I've edited the tags, because there's nothing specific to Cognito or Angular about this question.

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.storage` is storage specific to the extension, not to your page.

Namely, `chrome.storage.sync` is stored in the cloud and syncs with all your browser installations through [Chrome Sync](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sync/model-api/), as long as they are logged to the same account on your Chromium-based browser's sync provider (Google, Microsoft etc).

`chrome.storage.local` stores data only on your computer.

All this data lives in places separate from the page's `localStorage`.

To access your page's local storage, you'll need to use the usual `localStorage` api in a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/). This script runs in the web page's context and has access to all its resources (but not JavaScript).

The content script and the extension run in different isolates, so to communicate between them, you'll need to use the [messaging subsystem](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/).